# performance click event with append divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have a div and I append another div(s) using jQuery `append` or `html`.

I searched about appending elements with jQuery.

Which is better?

Append using string like this:

```
$('#div_main').append('<div id="div_sub" onclick="func(param);"></div>')
```

or:

```
$('#div_main').append($('<div id="div_sub"></div>').click(function(){ func(param) }))
```

I tried the first which is the faster one but which is better in performance?

Note the `append` in loop.

Comment: 2 pieces of code you've provided do different jobs. They are not even comparable.

Comment: How not? On has inline event handling the other attaches the even in a click handler - if they WORK the same is something else, but the idea is clear. The second should be coded `$('<div id="div_sub"></div>').click(function(){ func(param) }).appendTo('#div_main')`

Comment: @zerkms If you actually know what you mean, it might make sense to explain. Either way, they do the *same* thing - bind a click handler to the appended `<div>`.

Comment: the idea about the performance the 2 code is the same result

Comment: `[id]` attributes must be unique. Use classes instead.

Comment: Not to be too picky, but technically the first one adds an `onclick` to the `#div_sub`, the second one adds a `click` handler to the `#div_main`.

Comment: @Ian: `append` is chained, it returns the original object. So in first case the `onclick` handler is bound to the added div (`#div_sub`), in the second - it's bound to the `#div_main`

Comment: @zerkms Crap, you're right. The first time I looked, I could've sworn they did it properly by appending `$('<div id="div_sub"></div>').click(function(){ func(param) })` and did the chaining properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither. You shouldn't be rebinding events for elements being added/removed dynamically. Instead you should be delegating events to their nearest stable parent:

```
$('#div_main').on('click', '.sub', function () {
   ...do stuff...
});

$(...).on('click', function () {
    $('#div_main').append('<div class="sub"></div>');
});
```

Comment: do you mean appending elements using events is better performance than using inline ??

Comment: Besides the multiple drawbacks of using inline `onclick`s, using a delegate on a parent element is certainly better for performance than adding individual handlers on each element.  Especially when you have a lot of children elements.

Comment: @AhmadAlkhalil, focus less on the performance of the code, and more on the performance of the programmer. Delegated events avoid the issue of having to juggle event bindings when elements are added and removed.

Comment: @zzzzBov thnx :) but we are at my work the performance of the code and the speed is more important :(

Comment: @AhmadAlkhalil, then the correct solution is to measure the performance to decide which approach is more performant. Performance of code is completely subjective in where it's used.

Comment: @zzzzBov thnx very much :)

Answer (score 1):

jsperf.com is a good way to test things like this. Using the DOM significantly outperforms either of the jQuery code samples (they perform about equally). Have a look: http://jsperf.com/clickers

```
var main = document.getElementById('div_main'),
    clicker = document.createElement('div');

clicker.onclick = function() { func(param) };
main.appendChild(clicker);
```

Comment: +1 for actually providing performance data.  However, it should probably be noted that @zzzzBov's answer above beats all three approaches, as it only uses one handler, rather than one for each child element.

Comment: @Steve, depends on how many of these "clickers" are actually being added. Since the element has an ID, I'm assuming only one is being added, so you might as well give it the click event.